# How do you isolate a kernel call for a program using WinDbg?

Tags: windows, kernel, windbg

I'm trying to use WinDbg to debug a kernel call that occurs when I'm loading a specific program. There is an error occuring inside the kernel mode code. Kernel functions are extremely common calls occuring many times per second on the many processes running on the machine. Thus, how does one isolate a kernel call to debug it? For example, if I place a breakpoint on nt!NtCreateSection or ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection, WinDbg is going to break so many times that I can't even go to the OS and launch the program in question because it will be breaking on the calls to these functions that all other programs in memory are using rather than for the target program I'm trying to debug. Please specify a method to address this problem and target a specific instance(s) of a kernel call or some other solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sxe ld your module.
once you break on your module
find the eprocess with !process 0 0 your module.
set process specific breakpoint
like bp /p eprocess symbol.

or hard patch the entry point of your module with 0xcc and follow from there

you can also debug it with redirection using ntsd -d your module

you can also force symbol loading with !gflags + ksl if needed